# LibGDX GWT compiler doesn’t work, can’t find solution

Tags: eclipse, html, gwt, libgdx

I’ve been trying literally for hours to figure out what is wrong with my GWT compiler in Eclipse. I’ve looked all over the internet and tried a ton of solutions and none of them work for me. When I try to compile my LibGdx project this is the log: http://pastebin.com/ZCr3qXgs.

I already tried reinstalling everything to the latest version.

Comment: Have you tried it using the command line? With admin rights, call `gradlew.bat html:dist` or `gradlew html:dist` if you are using a mac

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't seem to find out how to run that command in cmd, because when I open cmd it just opens on C:/WINDOWS/system32. And typing gradlew.bat html:dist there won't do anything.

Comment: I also tried typing the command in: "run/external tools/external tools configuration..." then "Gradle (STS) build/MyGame-html". But it comes with this error: http://pastebin.com/SNHpnvdn

Comment: Shift + Right Click in the folder opens a command window in that folder

Comment: Thanks, I can do that but it can't find the tools.jar file: http://prntscr.com/cwdh00

Comment: I got it to work, but when I open the index.html it just shows the dark gray screen with the circular arrow button on the browser.

Comment: Now when compiling it crashes and it just says: :html:clean FAILED.